# Django filter queryset based on many to many extra fields model

Tags: django

Here is a models example.

```
class Person(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

      def __unicode__(self):
          return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

      def __unicode__(self):
          return self.name

class Membership(models.Model):
      person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
      group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
```

I want to get all Person objects, and for each one adding a column 'is_member' that values True if the person is member at least of one group.

I try with annotate and count, but I'm a bit confused... Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
Person.objects.annotate(
    is_member=Case(
        When(membership=True, then=True), default=False, output_field=BooleanField()
        )
    ).distinct('id')
```

if you want learn more about this, [conditional-expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/1.10/ref/models/conditional-expressions/) can help u.

Comment: This is very interesting, thank you. However, I don't understand why is_member is always false (i have data in the table)

Comment: oh, nice, i will ask for u show me the result of Person.objects.annotate(qty_membership=Count('membership)) hauhahu but ok.

Comment: this is strange, because here i just have this fields
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'foo' into field. Choices are: id, membership, name, for some reason, your model use membership_person..

Comment: @user1518217, can u mark as a answer and upvote? thanks.

Comment: I'm testing it because something gets wrong... for the moment i upvote because it's been useful (thank you!)

Comment: did u put the distinct('id') at the end?

Answer (score 0):

The following should work for you:

```
persons = []
for p in Person.objects.all():
    if p.membership_set.all():
        p.is_member = True
    else:
        p.is_member = False
    persons.append(p)
```